# How do you push items to an object in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to push data to a `ng-object` after filling and submitting an html form with user defined values. After pressing on submit, values are pushed, but with duplicated data.

I tried clearing `$scope.user > $scope.user='';`

I tried clearing the input boxes after submit.

### NG code below

```
var app = angular.module('ngpractice', []);

app.controller("formWorking", function($scope){
$scope.data = [];
$scope.update = function(){
    //$scope.data = angular.copy(user); 
    $scope.data.push($scope.user)
}
$scope.reset = function(){
    $scope.data = [];
    console.log('Data Wiped !')
}
});
```

### html code

```
<div ng-controller="formWorking">
<h2>Working with Forms</h2>
<form>
<fieldset id="myForm">
Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" ng-model="user.firstname"/>
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname" ng-model="user.lastname"         
                  required</>
<br>
Gender M: <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" ng-model="user.gender"/>
Gender F: <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" ng-model="user.gender" />
<input type="button" value="save" ng-click="update()"/>
<input type="button" value="reset" ng-click="reset()"/>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

`$scope.data = [];` should display different objects provided by form after submitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Push a copy to the array:

```
$scope.update = function(){
    //$scope.data = angular.copy(user); 
    ̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶d̶a̶t̶a̶.̶p̶u̶s̶h̶(̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶u̶s̶e̶r̶)̶
    var copy = Object.assign({}, $scope.user)
    $scope.data.push(copy);
}
```

For more information, see

- [MDN JavaScript Reference - Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: Pointed me into the right direction. Thank you very much. Do you have a quick explanation on why this behavior. I kind off can see why. 

The code provided created an empty object. The below version worked: 


 $scope.update = function(){
  
  let copy = angular.copy($scope.user)
  $scope.data.push(copy)
  console.log($scope.data);
 }

    // pushes new input to $scope.data=[] every-time user saves input on html form.